# Running into a segfault in C

Tags: c, pointers

Edit: working code at the bottom

Im relatively new to programming, and Im trying to understand why this isnt working. I decided to deal cards through a function instead of `main()` to keep it as modular as possible. Here's my code below; I know the error is something to do with the pointers, but I dont understand what Im doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int dealCards (char* cards[52][30], int* x, int* y, int* a, int* b)
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    printf("\n\nNow let's give you two random cards!\n\n");

    *x = rand() % 53;
    if (x != 0) {
        *x = x - 1;
    }

    *y = rand() % 53;
    if (y == x) {
        while (y == x) {
            y = rand() % 53;
        }
    }
    if (y != 0) {
        y = y - 1;
    }

    int i;
    printf("Card 1 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*x][i]);
        }
    printf("\nCard 2 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*y][i]);
        }

    printf("\n%d\n", x);
    printf("%d", y);

    printf("\n\nNow let's give your opponent two random cards!\n\n");

    *a = rand() % 53;
    if (a != 0) {
        a = a - 1;
    }
    if ((a == x) || (a == y)) {
        while ((a == x) || (a == y)) {
            *a = rand() % 53;
        }
    }

    *b = rand() % 53;
    if (b == a) {
        while ((b == a) || (b == x) || (b == y)) {
                *b = rand() % 53;
        }
    }
    if (b != 0) {
        *b = b - 1;
    }

    printf("Card 1 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*a][i]);
        }
    printf("\nCard 2 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*b][i]);
        }

    printf("\n%d\n", a);
    printf("%d", b);
}

int main()
{
    char deck[52][30] = { 
        {"_____\n|2♥ |\n|   |\n|_2♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♥ |\n|   |\n|_3♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♥ |\n|   |\n|_4♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♥ |\n|   |\n|_5♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♥ |\n|   |\n|_6♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♥ |\n|   |\n|_7♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♥ |\n|   |\n|_8♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♥ |\n|   |\n|_9♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♥|\n|   |\n|10♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♥ |\n|   |\n|_J♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♥ |\n|   |\n|_Q♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♥ |\n|   |\n|_K♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♥ |\n|   |\n|_A♥|\n"},

        {"_____\n|2♦ |\n|   |\n|_2♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♦ |\n|   |\n|_3♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♦ |\n|   |\n|_4♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♦ |\n|   |\n|_5♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♦ |\n|   |\n|_6♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♦ |\n|   |\n|_7♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♦ |\n|   |\n|_8♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♦ |\n|   |\n|_9♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♦|\n|   |\n|10♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♦ |\n|   |\n|_J♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♦ |\n|   |\n|_Q♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♦ |\n|   |\n|_K♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♦ |\n|   |\n|_A♦|\n"},

        {"_____\n|2♠ |\n|   |\n|_2♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♠ |\n|   |\n|_3♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♠ |\n|   |\n|_4♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♠ |\n|   |\n|_5♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♠ |\n|   |\n|_6♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♠ |\n|   |\n|_7♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♠ |\n|   |\n|_8♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♠ |\n|   |\n|_9♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♠|\n|   |\n|10♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♠ |\n|   |\n|_J♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♠ |\n|   |\n|_Q♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♠ |\n|   |\n|_K♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♠ |\n|   |\n|_A♠|\n"},

        {"_____\n|2♣ |\n|   |\n|_2♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♣ |\n|   |\n|_3♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♣ |\n|   |\n|_4♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♣ |\n|   |\n|_5♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♣ |\n|   |\n|_6♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♣ |\n|   |\n|_7♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♣ |\n|   |\n|_8♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♣ |\n|   |\n|_9♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♣|\n|   |\n|10♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♣ |\n|   |\n|_J♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♣ |\n|   |\n|_Q♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♣ |\n|   |\n|_K♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♣ |\n|   |\n|_A♣|\n"},
    };

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            printf("%c", deck[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //dealing
    int heroFirst, heroSecond, villainFirst, villainSecond;

    dealCards(deck, &heroFirst, &heroSecond, &villainFirst, &villainSecond);


    //bets
}
```

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int dealCards (char cards[52][30], int *x, int *y, int *a, int *b)
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    printf("\n\nYour cards:\n\n");

    *x = rand() % 53;
    if (*x != 0) {
        *x = *x - 1;
    }

    *y = rand() % 53;
    if (*y == *x) {
        while (*y == *x) {
            *y = rand() % 53;
        }
    }
    if (*y != 0) {
        *y = *y - 1;
    }

    int i;
    printf("Card 1 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*x][i]);
        }
    printf("\nCard 2 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*y][i]);
        }

    printf("\n\nVillain cards:\n\n");

    *a = rand() % 53;
    if (*a != 0) {
        *a = *a - 1;
    }
    if ((*a == *x) || (*a == *y)) {
        while ((*a == *x) || (*a == *y)) {
            *a = rand() % 53;
        }
    }

    *b = rand() % 53;
    if (*b == *a) {
        while ((*b == *a) || (*b == *x) || (*b == *y)) {
                *b = rand() % 53;
        }
    }
    if (*b != 0) {
        *b = *b - 1;
    }

    printf("Card 1 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*a][i]);
        }
    printf("\nCard 2 >\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*b][i]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    char deck[52][30] = { 
        {"_____\n|2♥ |\n|   |\n|_2♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♥ |\n|   |\n|_3♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♥ |\n|   |\n|_4♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♥ |\n|   |\n|_5♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♥ |\n|   |\n|_6♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♥ |\n|   |\n|_7♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♥ |\n|   |\n|_8♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♥ |\n|   |\n|_9♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♥|\n|   |\n|10♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♥ |\n|   |\n|_J♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♥ |\n|   |\n|_Q♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♥ |\n|   |\n|_K♥|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♥ |\n|   |\n|_A♥|\n"},

        {"_____\n|2♦ |\n|   |\n|_2♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♦ |\n|   |\n|_3♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♦ |\n|   |\n|_4♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♦ |\n|   |\n|_5♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♦ |\n|   |\n|_6♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♦ |\n|   |\n|_7♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♦ |\n|   |\n|_8♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♦ |\n|   |\n|_9♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♦|\n|   |\n|10♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♦ |\n|   |\n|_J♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♦ |\n|   |\n|_Q♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♦ |\n|   |\n|_K♦|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♦ |\n|   |\n|_A♦|\n"},

        {"_____\n|2♠ |\n|   |\n|_2♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♠ |\n|   |\n|_3♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♠ |\n|   |\n|_4♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♠ |\n|   |\n|_5♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♠ |\n|   |\n|_6♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♠ |\n|   |\n|_7♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♠ |\n|   |\n|_8♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♠ |\n|   |\n|_9♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♠|\n|   |\n|10♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♠ |\n|   |\n|_J♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♠ |\n|   |\n|_Q♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♠ |\n|   |\n|_K♠|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♠ |\n|   |\n|_A♠|\n"},

        {"_____\n|2♣ |\n|   |\n|_2♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|3♣ |\n|   |\n|_3♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|4♣ |\n|   |\n|_4♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|5♣ |\n|   |\n|_5♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|6♣ |\n|   |\n|_6♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|7♣ |\n|   |\n|_7♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|8♣ |\n|   |\n|_8♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|9♣ |\n|   |\n|_9♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|10♣|\n|   |\n|10♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|J♣ |\n|   |\n|_J♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|Q♣ |\n|   |\n|_Q♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|K♣ |\n|   |\n|_K♣|\n"},
        {"_____\n|A♣ |\n|   |\n|_A♣|\n"},
    };

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            printf("%c", deck[i][j]);
        }
    }

    double heroStack, villainStack;
    printf("\n-----------------------------");
    printf("\nWelcome to Heads Up Hold 'Em!");
    printf("\n-----------------------------");

    printf("\nHow many chips are your going to start off with?\n> ");
    scanf("%lf", &heroStack);
    villainStack = heroStack;

    printf("\nYour chipstack: %.lf\n", heroStack);
    printf("Villain's chipstack: %.lf\n", villainStack);

    //dealing
    int heroFirst, heroSecond, villainFirst, villainSecond;

    dealCards(deck, &heroFirst, &heroSecond, &villainFirst, &villainSecond);
    printf("\n%d\n", heroFirst);
    printf("%d\n", heroSecond);
    printf("%d\n", villainFirst);
    printf("%d\n", villainSecond);

    //bets
    //double heroBet, villainBet;
    //printf("\nYour move");
}
```

Comment: `char* cards[52][30]` --> `char cards[52][30]`

Comment: `*x = x - 1;` - Doesn't it look suspicious? `a = a - 1;` - while `a` is a pointer? And many, many similar issues.

Comment: Always take your compiler's warning serious.

Comment: You should be getting compiler warnings for that code. Turn on/up compiler warnings and fix them! (For `gcc` add `-Wall` to the compile line.)

Comment: Also this `if (y != 0) {
        y = y - 1;
    }` ought to be `if (*y != 0) {
        *y = *y - 1;
    }` Same for all non `*` prefixed `a`, `b`, `x` and `y`.

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once).

Comment: `*x = rand() % 53` produces an array index in the range `0` to `52` which will break the bounds when used as `cards[*x][i]`

Comment: @WeatherVane - I think OP tries to subtract 1 (if `*x` isn't zero) so it shouldn't go out of bounds. But `if (x != 0) {*x = x - 1;}` isn't the way to do it... However, I find it strange that OP doesn't use `% 52` from the start.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Im trying to pass `deck[][]` as an argument for a pointer in my `dealCards()` function.

Comment: @alk Can you recommend a resource to clarify this for me? Im trying to understand when to add the `*` before each variable and when I dont have to. Im learning C on my own.

Comment: @4386427 I did not use `% 52` in because there are 52 cards in the deck, `deck[0][0]` being `2♥` and `deck[52][0]` being `A♣`. The range `% 53` chooses an int between `0` and `52`, which is what I need

Comment: @4386427 thanks didn't notice that but index `0` now is twice as likely. Loaded deck. And as pointed out should be `if(*x != 0) {*x = *x - 1;}` not `if(x != 0) {*x = x - 1;}`

Comment: @MichaelKhoussid `char* cards[52][30]` meant 2D-Array of `char*`.

Comment: @WeatherVane How can I circumvent this and ensure optimal randomness?

Comment: With `card = rand() % 52` and worry about the quality of the RNG distribution when the code works. But for a casual game exercise, that's unimportant.

Comment: Also when `Type array[n]`, The elements are `array[0]`...`array[n-1]`. `array[n]` is out of bounds.

Comment: You might like to chose one more of the resources listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/694576

Comment: @MichaelKhoussid - You commented that `deck[52][0] being A♣`. That is wrong - `deck[51]` is holding the string for A♣. Access to `deck[52]` is illegal.

Comment: @4386427 Apologies, that's what I meant

Comment: @MichaelKhoussid And therefore you should do `% 52` and remove the code where you subtract 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing confusingly between getting value and calculating value
This `if` (and similar), do you know what are you doing?

`*x = rand() % 53;
 if (x != 0) {
        *x = x - 1;
    }`

Well, `x` in your function is a pointer, which means, if you want to get or to assign a value, you must use operator `*` like `*x = rand() % 53`
But when you compare `x != 0`, the compiler will think that you are checking whether x is NULL or not (by default, NULL is `0`). So, it is not the value of the above statement, which will lead you to logic error.

If you look closer in your `main`, you should see that `x`, `y`, and similar argument you pass is never NULL, since they are created locally in `main` function and still existing until you leave it. Therefore, your statement `*x = x - 1` will work unexpectedly, which may cause your segfault

<s>I think that you are using the deal function to get randomly values of these variables</s>

`int heroFirst, heroSecond, villainFirst, villainSecond;`

Thus, you can pass those value by reference by declare the function like this:
`int dealCards (char cards[52][30], int& x, int& y, int& a, int& b)`
then call your function like this
`dealCards (deck, heroFirst, heroSecond, villainFirst, villainSecond)`

In your dealCards definition, just remove the `*` like `*x` or something like that, your function will work normally (if you know what you are going to do, with those `x` `y`)

Moreover, you can safely print the whole string without using for loop like this, it seem crappy, isn't it?

`for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            printf("%c", cards[*y][i]);
        }`

Just print it normally by
`printf("%s", cards[*y]);`

Eddited:

- Grammar
- You should re-declare your cardDecks as above comments to make it works

Comment: This is a C question - passing by reference as you've described doesn't exist. Maybe you're thinking of C++?

Comment: Thank you, but the reason I initially chose to use pointers such as `*x` is because I didnt want to return anything from the `dealCards` function, because Im not sure how to do that. Whenever I try to return values, I call function in my `main` and then I test by `printf("%d", heroFirst)` and it throws me a random number not in the `0 - 52` range

Comment: @ChrisTurner, Oops, sorry about that, thanks for notice me (y)
@MichaelKhoussid it is random because of this and similar lines:
`*x = x - 1;`
You should change to `*x = *x - 1` instead

Comment: @LoiLy you should edit your answer and remove the misleading stuff that is ruining an otherwise useful answer